# Is there a python library that can return the format (%d %m %y) of the incoming date (14-05-2010)?

Tags: python-3.x, date-formatting, date-parsing

I got the need to format the input date using python3, thanks.

For example :

input:
1) date_string (23-11-1894)
2) date_string (1894-23-11)

output:
1) "DMY" or ["% d", "% m", "% y"]
2) "YDM" or ["% y", "% d", "% m"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` module can probably do what you are looking for:

```
import datetime

abc = datetime.datetime.strptime("1894-11-24","%Y-%m-%d")
print("Year: ",abc.year,"  Month: ",abc.month,"  Day: ",abc.day)
```

You just have to specify what your data looks like in `strptime()` and it will create a `date` object which can be used.

Comment: So of course, but the data are diverse and I can not specify the format, the problem is that there is a sample of dates and I need to make out what format of the date prevails in this sample.
I can't specify "%Y-%m-%d" in abc = datetime.datetime.strptime("1894-11-24","%Y-%m-%d"), this row should be the result of the work.

Comment: How would your hypothetical code distinguish between `YMD: 1999-1-1` and `YDM: 1999-1-1`? If you don't know the date format in advance, or at least that it will be consistent, you can't reliably read that data.

Comment: read about python lib dateparser, i do not have to specify date format in it
dateparser.parse("1999-1-1") and it automatically recognizes the format, i have a few samples of data with same format but i don't know exactly which format, i would like her to return the date format which is correct in her opinion for each date, and then assign to those dates the most offen recognized format, but she can only return datetime for each date, but not her format.

Comment: Ok, so you have a bunch of data with the same format but you don't know the format.  Passing it into `dateparser.parse()` that function will guess what format your data is in.  If all some your data is of the format "MM-DD-YYYY" or "YYYY-DD-MM" and NONE IS EVER of the format "DD-MM-YYYY" or "YYYY-MM-DD" you will be ok.  But, if you have these mixed in you might need to check all your month values, if they are higher than 12 you are not reading months, those are days.